# Ideal of a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Let $F$ be a field. Show that  $S$ be a non empty subset of $F^{n} $ then

$ I(S) =$ {  $    f(x) \in F[x] \hspace{0.1in} \vert  \hspace{0.1in}f(s) = 0  \hspace{0.1in}   \forall  s \in S  $ }

is an ideal of $F[x]$

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I am stuck.I tried by taking kernel of a ring but couldn't do much.

Comment: I think it is a matter of applying the definition.

Comment: Is $x$ understood as $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ here?

Answer (score 1):

The ideal-idea is fine. For fixed $s$, the evaluation $F[x]\to F$, $f\mapsto f(s)$ is a ring homomorphism.

Comment: Could you please elaborate ?

Comment: @sammath By definition of $F[x]$ via its universal property: For every ring hom $F\to A$ and every map $x\to A$ there exists a unique ring hom $F[x]\to A$ such that ...